# Wait for file to exist and be not ocupated by others

Tags: c++, linux, file-io, filesystems, c++17

### Question

How can I monitor my file system to read file just after creation. This will work on Linux based system but it would be nice if solution would be cross-platform. Important requirement is that, there shouldn't be any other file descriptor that could write to that config file.

I have read about [inotify](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) but this isn't cross-platform and required a lot of knowledge. I am curious about new c++17 file-system module.

*I can do it by simple `while(!fileexist(fielanme)) sleep(1);` But I curious abut more mature solutions*

### Background

I am writing application that can be configured from API (REST). But once configured can start easy (store configuration file).

So I think its a good way to separate this task for two:

1. REST -> just create file with conf.
2. Main wait for file to exist and block file to be open by other in write mode while reading configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no cross-platform way to do this. The best way to do it is to write the file to a temporary name, then rename it to the file that the application is looking for. On most operating systems the `rename()` operation is atomic. Then the reading application can simply wait for the file to exist.

So the structure of your waiting code could be (this is pseudo-code):

```
while (true) {
    if (file_exists(filename)) {
        process the file
        remove the file
    }
    sleep(wait_time);
}
```

Comment: Yea. I hear about `rename()` is a good solution. So u vote just for simple `while`?

Comment: https://github.com/simongeilfus/Watchdog is a work in progress for a cross-platform solution.  But in general, watching for filesystem changes is at the intersection of async and file io that is poorly standardized.